# SortExpression not working in ASP.NET If Header Text is passed dynamically through VB code

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using below aspx code for Column 6(This column number has reference in .vb code and code is mentioned below aspx code):

```
<asp:BoundField ControlStyle-CssClass="dbody" DataField="order_date" HeaderText="Order Date" SortExpression="order_date">                            
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" ForeColor="White" />
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
```

On aspx.vb page I am using below code to pass dynamically Header Text:

```
 If iOrderType = 4 Then
                        gvOrders.HeaderRow.Cells(6).Text = "DVN date" 
                    ElseIf iOrderType = 11 Then
                        gvOrders.HeaderRow.Cells(6).Text = "Lab Order Date" 
                    Else
                        gvOrders.HeaderRow.Cells(6).Text = "Order Date" 
                    End If
```

Now after running application my sixth column is not working as sorting expression link. Also in asp grid view tag AllowSorting is "true" and gvOrder is grid id.

[image: Grid Header Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a header cell with sorting enabled, the `DataControlField` will add a `LinkButton` to the `TableCell`, and set its properties accordingly.

When you set the `TableCell`'s `Text` property, it removes all of the controls which were created by the `DataControlField`. This includes the `LinkButton` used to sort the cell.

You need to change the text of the `LinkButton` instead.

```VB
Dim text As String
If iOrderType = 4 Then
    text = "DVN date" 
ElseIf iOrderType = 11 Then
    text = "Lab Order Date" 
Else
    text = "Order Date" 
End If

Dim cell As TableCell = gvOrders.HeaderRow.Cells(6)
Dim button As IButtonControl = If(cell.HasControls(), TryCast(cell.Controls(0), IButtonControl), Nothing)
If button Is Nothing Then
    cell.Text = text
Else
    button.Text = text
End If
```